# Bootstrap 3 : Filter content of input field using css

Tags: html, css, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to only number inputs. I am trying to filter the input field using `type='number'` . But I can enter non-numbers also. How to prevent inputing non-numbers?

```
<input type="number"  style="background-color:#f5f5f5;"  class="form-control" placeholder="number">
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mridulpv/CXXqY/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write some kind of JavaScript validation Or try jquery form validation plugin

Answer (score 0):

here is a jquery plugin

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

it allow filter inputs